# Displaying landcover classes using Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, land-cover

I was wondering if theres a way to display single Landcover classes from the Corine Land Cover-Dataset in GEE. I know i somehow have to select the landcover_class_names or values in the property section of the image but I'm not sure how to do that.

```
var corine = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/CORINE/V18_5_1/100m').first();

print(corine);
print(corine.propertyNames());
var lc_value = corine.get('landcover_class_values');
print(lc_value);
```

Thats my code so far. Now i only want to display the forest areas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to display a single value (or set of values) in the Map Viewer then I suggest using the `ee.Image.updateMask()` function. This will set all values in the input image that correspond to 0 values in the mask image to no data.

Here is the code for your example:

```
var corine = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/CORINE/V18_5_1/100m').first();

print(corine);
print(corine.propertyNames());
var lc_value = corine.get('landcover_class_values');
print(lc_value);

var forest = corine.updateMask(corine.gte(23).and(corine.lte(32)))

Map.addLayer(forest)
```

I looked at the Corine image metadata to find which values are forest (23-34) and used logical operators to get an binary image as the mask image to `.updateMask()`. I hope this helps!